# How do I read multiple results sets from a PostgreSQL function using Dapper?

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I am trying to understand how to use Dapper to make a call to a PostgreSQL function that returns multiple result sets. My understanding is that in PostgreSQL, the best (only?) way to currently achieve this is to declare that the function `RETURNS SETOF REFCURSOR`.

### Example PostgreSQL Function that Returns Multiple `REFCURSOR`s

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.testmultiplerefcursorfunc()
    RETURNS SETOF REFCURSOR
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    STABLE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
    ref1    REFCURSOR;
    ref2    REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

    OPEN ref1 FOR
    SELECT      *
    FROM        characters;
    RETURN NEXT ref1;

    OPEN ref2 FOR
    SELECT      *
    FROM        planets;
    RETURN NEXT ref2;

END;
$BODY$;
```

### Broken Dapper+PostgreSQL with Multiple `REFCURSOR`s Example

```cs
[Test]
public void UsingDapper_QueryMultiple_CallFunctionThatReturnsMultipleRefCursors_ReadsMultipleResultSetsViaMultipleRefCursors()
{
    // Arrange
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_getConnectionStringToDatabase()))
    {
        var funcName = "testmultiplerefcursorfunc";
        var expect1 = CharacterTestData;
        var expect2 = PlanetTestData;
        conn.Open();

        using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            // Act
            using (var results = conn.QueryMultiple(
                funcName, 
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
                transaction: transaction))
            {
                var result1 = results.Read<Character>().AsList();
                var result2 = results.Read<Planet>().AsList();

                // Assert 
                CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expect1, result1);
                CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expect2, result2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm having with the code above is that when I make the first `results.Read<T>()` call, it attempts to return both `REFCURSOR`s cast as `T`. This cast then results in a `T` with `null` values for all of the properties. Then the next call to `results.Read<T>()` throws the following exception:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'The reader has been disposed; this can happen after all data has been consumed
Object name: 'Dapper.SqlMapper+GridReader'.'
```

So, **how does Dapper work with multiple PostgreSQL `REFCURSOR`s?** Is there a way to read the results without manually dereferencing the cursors?

I've got a vanilla example that returns multiple `REFCURSOR`s without using Dapper that works where I manually dereference the cursors and read the results and I've also got examples that work against a SQL Server stored procedure that return multiple results.

I haven't (yet) found any particular documentation that points to a specific difference of how `QueryMultiple` should be called for PostgreSQL vs SQL Server, but such documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Even when calling a PostgreSQL function that returns single `REFCURSOR` using Dapper, I've found it necessary to manually handle the cursor dereferencing like the example below.

But from what I've read so far, this doesn't seem like it's *supposed* to be necessary, although I've had trouble finding specific documentation/examples for Dapper+PostgreSQL that show how this should otherwise work.

### Working Dapper+PostgreSQL with Single `REFCURSOR` Example

```cs
[Test]
public void UsingDapper_Query_CallFunctionThatReturnsRefCursor_ReadsRowsViaRefCursor()
{
    // Arrange
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_getConnectionStringToDatabase()))
    {
        var procName = "testrefcursorfunc";
        var expect = CharacterTestData;
        conn.Open();

        using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            // Act
            var cursorResult = (IDictionary<string, object>)conn
                .Query<dynamic>(procName, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, transaction: transaction)
                .Single();
            var cursorSql = $@"FETCH ALL FROM ""{(string)cursorResult[procName]}""";
            var result = conn.Query<Character>(
                cursorSql, 
                commandType: CommandType.Text, 
                transaction: transaction);

            // Assert 
            CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expect, result);
        }
    }
}
```

So, **with Dapper + PostgreSQL + `REFCURSOR`, is it always necessary to manually deference the cursor to read the results?** Or can Dapper handle that for you?

Answer (score 1):

Coming from an sql server background where its just a question of a list of select statements in your stored proc and your "good to go"; using postgresql and the requirement to use refcursors and  "fetch " those refcusors on the other side can be quite painful.

What i can suggest is:

1.) Use a postgresql Procedure with refcursors as INOUT parameters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.proc_testmultiplerefcursor(INOUT ref1 refcursor, INOUT ref2 refcursor)
```

2.) Call the procedure and then fetch the refcursors for the returned data using "FETCH ALL".

Fill the INOUT parameters with names for refcursors so they are recoverable in this case i have used 'ref1' & 'ref2'.

```
var sql = "BEGIN;CALL public.proc_testmultiplerefcursor(@pentity_id,'ref1','ref2');" +
                  "FETCH ALL FROM  ref1; " +
                  "FETCH ALL FROM  ref2;" +
                  "COMMIT;";
```

3.) Then your usual Dapper QueryMutliple and Reads.

```
var multi = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync(sql);
var result1 = (await multi.ReadAsync<Character>()).AsList();
var result2 =(await multi.ReadAsync<Planet>()).AsList();
```

This is untested but i hope it can be of help. Postgresql is painfull but brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this problem lately, and to *imitate* the multiple result set behavior of SQL Server, I used a function that returns **SETOF REFCURSOR**. I made my own simple library to resolve this problem, so I can reuse it to my other projects. See my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/kblyr/CodeCompanion.Extensions.Dapper.Postgres)

Assuming you have 5 tables in the database

- User

  - **Id**
  - **Username**
- Role

  - **Id**
  - **Name**
- Permission

  - **Id**
  - **Name**
- UserRole

  - **UserId** | FK: *User.Id*
  - **RoleId** | FK: *Role.Id*
- RolePermission

  - **RoleId** | FK: *Role.Id*
  - **PermissionId** | FK: *Permission.Id*

#### PostgreSQL (PL/PGSQL)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "get_user_with_roles_and_permissions"("user__id" INTEGER)
RETURNS SETOF REFCURSOR AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    -- Refcursor declarations
    "ref__user" REFCURSOR;
    "ref__roles" REFCURSOR;
    "ref__permissions" REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    -- Select User
    -- NOTE: this only query for exactly 1 row
    OPEN "ref__user" FOR
    SELECT "User"."Id", "User"."Username"
    FROM "User"
    WHERE "User"."Id" = "user__id"
    LIMIT 1;
    RETURN NEXT "ref__user";

    -- Select Roles
    OPEN "ref__roles" FOR
    SELECT "Role"."Id", "Role"."Name"
    FROM "Role"
    INNER JOIN "UserRole" ON "Role"."Id" = "UserRole"."RoleId"
    WHERE "UserRole"."UserId" = "user__id";
    RETURN NEXT "ref__roles";

    -- Select Permissions
    -- NOTE: There's a chance that user has many roles which have same permission, we use DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates
    OPEN "ref__permissions" FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT "Permission"."Id", "Permission"."Name"
    FROM "Permission"
    INNER JOIN "RolePermission" ON "Permission"."Id" = "RolePermission"."PermissionId"
    INNER JOIN "UserRole" ON "RolePermission"."RoleId" = "UserRole"."RoleId"
    WHERE "UserRole"."UserId" = "user__id";
    RETURN NEXT "ref__permissions";
END;
$BODY$
```

#### C#

```cs
/* Entity models */
record User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

record Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

record Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Calling the database function in C# code

// Create an instance of NpgsqlConnection
using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);

// Try to open a database connection
connection.Open();

// Begin a database transaction
using var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

// Query refcursors
// Call a function with name 'get_user_with_roles_and_permissions' with parameter 'user_id' = 1
var refcursors = connection.QueryRefcursor("get_user_with_roles_and_permissions", transaction, new { user__id = 1 });

// we use ReadSingleOrDefault because we're sure that there is only one user that has an id of 1 (or none if the user with id = 1 doesn't exists)
var user = refcursors.ReadSingleOrDefault<User>();

// Check if user with id = 1 exists
if (user is not null)
{
    // Query for roles
    user.Roles = refcursors.Read<Role>();

    // Query for permissions
    user.Permissions = refcursors.Read<Permission>(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with conn.QueryMultipleAsync In Current source you are using conn.QueryMultiple. Here is the complete guide for it . [Dapper Multiple](https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/52035882/csharp-dapper--getting-multiple-result-sets-from-stored-procedure-)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Like this. Sure It Will Work..!

```
public DataSet Manage_user_profiledata(string _prof_code)
        {
            string query = string.Format(@"select * from  Function_Name(@prof_code, @first_tbl, @second_tbl)");
            NpgsqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new NpgsqlParameter[3];
            sqlParameters[0] = new NpgsqlParameter("@prof_code", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
            sqlParameters[0].Value = Convert.ToString(_prof_code);

            //
            sqlParameters[1] = new NpgsqlParameter("@first_tbl", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor);
            sqlParameters[1].Value = Convert.ToString("Avilable");
            sqlParameters[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            sqlParameters[1].NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor;
            //
            sqlParameters[2] = new NpgsqlParameter("@second_tbl", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor);
            sqlParameters[2].Value = Convert.ToString("Assigned");
            sqlParameters[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            sqlParameters[2].NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor;
            return conn.executeMultipleSelectQuery(query, sqlParameters);

        }





public DataSet executeMultipleSelectQuery(string _query, NpgsqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
        {
            // NgpSql Init //
            npg_connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connstr);
            npg_command = new NpgsqlCommand(_query, npg_connection);
            // NgpSql Init //
            i = 0;
            try
            {
                ds = new DataSet();
                npg_connection.Open();
                NpgsqlTransaction tran = npg_connection.BeginTransaction();
                npg_command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                npg_command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
                npg_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                foreach (NpgsqlParameter parm in sqlParameter)
                {
                    if (parm.NpgsqlDbType == NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor)
                    {
                        if (parm.Value.ToString() != "null" || parm.Value.ToString() != "NULL" || parm.Value.ToString() != "")
                        {
                            string parm_val = string.Format("FETCH ALL IN \"{0}\"", parm.Value.ToString());
                            npg_adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(parm_val.Trim().ToString(), npg_connection);
                            ds.Tables.Add(parm.Value.ToString());
                            npg_adapter.Fill(ds.Tables[i]);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                tran.Commit();
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ds_ERROR.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ex.ToString(), ex.Message.ToString());
                return ds_ERROR;
            }
            finally
            {
                npg_connection.Close();
            }
        }
```